# Trying to understand this short assembler instruction but I don't understand

Tags: assembly, instructions, addressing-mode

> We had a task, given was an assembler instruction of a 2-addressing
>   machine:
>
> ```
> mov 202, 100[r1+]
> ```
>
> Note down a minimal assembler instruction sequence which replaces this
>   instruction (see above)

where

- `n[rx+]`: register indexed by post increment; n is index value and rx is register x
- single numeric value: directly addressed / stored

The addresses we are supposed to use are:

1. `rx` - register direct addressing
2. `[rx]` - register indirect addressing
3. `#n` - directly addressing

And we are only allowed to use add, sub, mov.

I especially don't understand what # stands for and why we need substraction, well actually I don't really understand anything...
The task has been solved so I'm not looking for a solution. I need an explanation how it's done, trying to understand it myself but it didn't work.
I hope someone will be able and help me, would be so nice of you!

Solution:

```
add #100, r1
mov #202, r2
mov[r2],[r1]
sub #99, r1
```

Comment: A `#` prefix indicates an immediate constant in some assembly languages.  It looks like that's what it does in this one, too.

Comment: Wy are you not asking your instructor to explain? They're getting paid to provide you with the knowledge and understanding needed, and apparently they have not yet earned their pay. (Not downvoting - just asking.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Understand that assembly language is not some universal standardized thing.  It is officially defined by the program that reads it which is the assembler.  So whatever that code defines as the language for that assembler is the language.  The machine code is what matters to the processor so you can have as many different assemblers and assembly languages as you have users so long as they all produce the right machine code.  So if you are expecting this to be universal one rule applies to all kind of thing that is not the case.

You have provided enough information though for experienced folks to see the habits of other assembly languages reflected here.

```
mov 202, 100[r1+]
```

So this appears to be moving what is at address of 202 register direct addressing as you stated.  to the location at address r1+100 register indexed and the post increment.

To replace that with more instructions since the one line is the simplest one as far as lines of code goes (as far as complexity and number of clocks not necessarily).

- So you need to read the contents of address 202,
- you need to add 100 to r1 temporarily,
- you need to write the contents of address 202 to the location r1+100,
- and then you need to take r1 and increment it (not the r1+100 incremented but r1 without the index incremented).

The solution given does pretty much that:

```
add #100, r1
mov #202, r2
mov[r2],[r1]
sub #99, r1
```

It adds 100 to r1 which we need to do temporarily (and will have to undo later because r1 is now wrong in the long run).
Then because they limit the addressing modes you need to have a register hold the address 202, so the value 202 is loaded into r2 just like the value 100 was added to r1.  The #number means just use this number.

Now you are allowed to use [rn] so the move reads what is at address r2 (address 202) and writes it to what is at address r1 (the original r1 plus 100).  Lastly because we want r1 to end up being the original plus 1 but we made it the original plus 100 we need to subtract off 99  r1+100-99 = r1+1

---

In C, it would be something like this:

```
unsigned *r1;
unsigned *r2;

//r1 is set somewhere in here to something that is not defined in your question or problem.

r1 += 100;  //add #100,r1
r2 = 202;   //mov #202,r2
*r1 = *r2; //mov [r2],[r1]
r1 -= 99;  //sub #99,r1
```

having the destination on the right and operand on the left is not intuitive since we mostly write and code with the result on the left and the operands on the right.

We don't code `202 = r2;`  we instead write `r2 = 202;` so `mov r2,#202` is more intuitive, but again assembly language is defined by the the folks that wrote the assembler and some folks like it left to right and others right to left.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time dwelch, really thank you very much for writing all this for me. I was hoping for having some answers when I come online next evening and it's just awesome! I don't understand it completely for sure but surely I have understood the basic idea and now I should be able to improve it from this point. ;)

Comment: off hand this does seem to be the shortest solution.  if one were to avoid the subtraction of 99 by using a third register I think that takes more instructions at least with what we know about this instruction set from your description.

Comment: break it into its individual parts.  some numbers are just numbers integers/immediates, the register holds some number and that number can in certain modes be an address or just some value.  so break the instructions into those parts.  I have a number it is a base address I add another number to it that is the address in memory.  that address in memory contains a number, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

In `mov 202, 100[r1+]`:

- The instruction is a `mov`
- The source operand is the memory at address `202`.  In some assembly languages, you could also write `[202]` for clarity.  There's no `#` on the number, so it's an absolute addressing mode, not an immediate.
- The destination operand is the memory at address `r1 + 100`.
- The side-effect of the addressing mode is `r1++`

Like many flavours of assembly language, this one apparently uses `#` prefixes to indicate immediate constants.  This is like GNU/AT&T x86 syntax, where `add $4, %eax` adds 4, but `add 4, %eax` loads a value from the absolute address `4`.

---

Your professor's given equivalent sequence adds 100 to `r1`, then subtracts `99`, since it wants to avoid displacements and post-increments in addressing modes.  It also clobbers `r2`, which the single-instruction version doesn't, so it's not a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I think someone came along and hated the question so much that they wanted to penalize people for even answering it and encouraging more questions like it.  The downvote on this answer appeared at the same time as a downvote on the question and other answer.

Comment: The question itself was downvoted as well :/. IMO this is very fair and reasonable question, with reasonable past and future effort shown by the OP, worth of these answers. It helps me as well to see what people struggle on (once you did some ASM coding, it's sort of elusive to understand newcomers problems), so I can help them next time more precisely and easily. I just sort of dislike their ASM variant, not specifying data width of operands - so it's unclear what amount of data is being moved around, would have been more instructive with optional b/w/d and `+` being sensitive to data size.

Comment: Again here thank you all very much for taking your time and helping me! :)
You are really good people!

Answer (score -2):

You solution does not map to the input at all. In your input, R1 is in an unknown state. In our "solution" R1 ends up at in a known state (1).

In addition, you'd have to know what your nation instruction format is.

```
mov 202, 100[r1+]
```

looks like it would

```
1) add 100 to the contents of R1 to create an address.
2) move 202 into that address
3) Add 2 to r1 (assuming a 2-byte machine word)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Since it's solution provided from our professor, I'm not sure what to think now :D

Comment: Your first paragraph is wrong.  @cnmesr's `mov [r2], [r1]` is a copy from memory to memory, and doesn't modify either register.  The net result of the code is `r1 += 1`, apparently the same as using `100[r1+]`.